# steps to recover lost files and data in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Recentlly i have installed ubuntu 12.04 and got to used with it ,but suddenly bymistake
i deleted few data and files ,so could you please tell me how to recovery the last data with steps .

Comment: To give you steps how to recover we need steps you took to delete your data. Please [edit] your question to include these.

Answer (score 0):

did you empty the trash bin? otherwise check the "Trash"
[image]

Comment: i have checked , trash can is empty